# Connection pooling is not reusing idle connections

Tags: java, database, postgresql, jdbc, hikaricp

I am pretty new to HikariCP, and I am running into an issue. I have a method to get a connection from the database using a HikariDataSource:

```java
public Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            return dataSource.getConnection();
        }
        catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

However, when I check pgAdmin (this is a PostgreSQL db btw), I see that instead of using idle connections, it creates a bunch of new connections. How can I fix this?

Below are some images of the connections table after I send a query to the db.
Initial:
[image: My initial connection_activity]

After a query:
[image: My connection_activity after a query]

You can see that in the first image there are 19 connections, with 18 of them being idle. But, after a query, there are a bunch of new connections, with most of them being idle. Did I configure Hikari wrong? Here is my configuration:

```java
config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/Postgres 13/BGWW Bot");
        config.setUsername();
        config.setPassword();
        config.addDataSourceProperty("max_connections", "120");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
        config.setDataSource(ds);
        config.setMaximumPoolSize(120);
        config.setMinimumIdle(15);
```

And finally, here is one of my methods that uses a connection from getConnection()

```java
public float[] getReqs()
    {
        try (Connection conn = getConnection())
        {
            String getReqs = "SELECT id, swstars, swwins, swkdr FROM reqs;";

            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(getReqs);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next())
            {
                if(rs.getInt(1) == 1)
                {
                    float[] array = new float[]{rs.getInt(2), rs.getInt(3), rs.getFloat(4)};
                    conn.close();
                    return array;
                }
            }

            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException throwables) {
            throwables.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You configuration says that the number of the connections in the pool should be between `15` and `120`.

You may with this configuration also observe more that `15` connections in the *idle* state.

The property `idleTimeout` controls the retirement of a connection if it is idle for such time (default - 10 minutes).

So in other words, only if your application makes no access for 10 minutes (plus 30 seconds as the connections are checked periodically with this period), you should expect to see the pool on the minimal size.

More information see [here](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#configuration-knobs-baby)

Comment: Hm, I used `config.setIdleTimeout()` to 11000 (11 seconds, for testing purposes), but after sending a query and waiting for 60 seconds, the idle connections are not deleted. What could be causing this? (I used `SELECT state FROM pg_stat_activity` in pgAdmin4)

Comment: Well @GouramEats you should definitively count only the connection from the *pool* and not all other! In your second image there are exact 15 sessions using `JDBC Driver`.

Comment: So to recap, the behavior I should see is: there are 15 queries from JDBC driver, then I query the DB, and add, say 5 more connections. Then, after 11 seconds (plus variations), I should see 15 connections again, with those 5 connections gone?

Comment: Actually, testing it, it worked! I noticed that instead of removing the connections from the pool, it changed the process id, indicating that it was freeing it up, so it did work. Thanks!